# Newbie question: how to access a created JComboBox instance from another method in the same class or else

Tags: java, swing, object, methods, jcombobox

If I have:

> Class A {
>
> ```
>     // bunch of stuff here
>
>     public void intitialize() {
>     // bunch of stuff here
>
>     JComboBox jBox = new JComboBox()
>
>     formatBox.addItem(//some objects added here))
>     //I do the rest of my business in this intitialize method
>
>     }
> ```
>
> }

if I want to add another method that when called can operate on jBox how can i do it? this code does not work:

```
Class A {

             // bunch of stuff here
             public void intitialize() {
             // bunch of stuff here
             JComboBox jBox = new JComboBox()
             formatBox.addItem(//some objects added here))
             //I do the rest of my business in this intitialize method
             }

            //newly added method
            public void anotherMethod(){

            jBox.removeItem(//some item here)

            }

}
```

What are the correct ways of writing this that allow jBox to be accessed from different methods of the class or other classes? and why doesn't it work this way ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use an instance variable and store the `JComboBox` there instead. If you want to access it from another class, you should probably create a public `getJBox()` method, that way the instance method can be private.

For example:

```
Class A {

    private JComboBox jBox;

    public void intitialize() {
        jBox = new JComboBox()

        formatBox.addItem(//some objects added here))
        //I do the rest of my business in this intitialize method

    }

    public JComboBox() getJBox() {
        return jBox;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

define the JComboBox as a field in Class A and remove the type declaration inside the `initialize` method:

```
Class A {
             private JComboBox  jBox;
             // bunch of stuff here
             public void intitialize() {
             // bunch of stuff here
             jBox = new JComboBox()
             formatBox.addItem(//some objects added here))
             //I do the rest of my business in this intitialize method
             }

            //newly added method
            public void anotherMethod(){

            jBox.removeItem(//some item here)

            }

}
```

Comment: Thanks :). You both gave the same answer, Adam answered my other question as well and thats why I accepted his answer. I wish it was possible to accept both answers.